# Roboguice injection and Provider class

Tags: android, code-injection, roboguice

In RoboGuice examples there are two different ways to inject something

```
@Inject
protected LayoutInflater inflater;

@Inject
protected Provider<LayoutInflater> inflater2;
```

What's the difference between them and what way and when i need to choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need provider to inject several instances of smth. For example, a row for an each user's action. Direct inject is used when you know what you want and size of your desires.

Provider is a fabric, that injected in you code